# npm rebuild node-sass not working ionic

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I was working on ionic project on Windows os then I tried to use it on ubuntu (linux os) but it told me to run `npm rebuild node-sass` so I did that but however this error keeps showing up and I tried to fix "file system is read-only" but nothing worked

```
npm rebuild node-sass
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-41-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "rebuild" "node-sass"
npm ERR! node v4.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path /media/bishoy/realwork/ambulancer/code/patients/node_modules/.bin/node-sass
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/media/bishoy/realwork/ambulancer/code/patients/node_modules/.bin/node-sass'
npm ERR! rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! rofs and is related to the file system being read-only.
npm ERR! rofs 
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-41-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "rebuild" "node-sass"
npm ERR! node v4.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.185227705
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, open 'npm-debug.log.185227705'
npm ERR! rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! rofs and is related to the file system being read-only.
npm ERR! rofs 
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/bishoy/realwork/ambulancer/code/patients/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `node_modules` and run `npm install`

Look here:

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install
```